# Azure web role with distributed background work

Tags: multithreading, azure, scalability, distributed-computing, azure-web-roles

I would like to create a wcf in web role to serve smartphone clients.

In addition, I need to create infinite background task that iterate over each member, and send push notification to the member if needed (the decision is made based on some facebook query for each member).

For the moment, the application is new and I don't have clients, and so I don't want more then one VM (for costs savings..), but I in the future i may need to scale so I want to support it.
The only requiment I have, is that the iterating over all the members will be completed in intervals of less then 30 minutes.

I was thinking about 2 solutions:

1. To run a classic windows service that runs only in one VM (if I scale out, still one instance for this windows service will be running on one of them only). moreover, i will add an "void Handle(Member member) method in the wcf service. the windows service will have infinite loop that sends wcf requests to this method.
this way, if i scale out my instance, the load balancing will distribute the work.

The problem: The windows service doesn't know how many concurrent requests he can send to the wcf service. i really need concurrent handling for the members (up to the limit the server can handle them in parallel of course) because while i wait for one facebook query to complete, i can send more facebook requests for other members (it takes a few seconds for each facebook query to response, because i use facebook batch requests).

2. Each webrole instance will be responsible for handling different members (i'm talking about the background work only). for example, if i have 2 instances (because i scaled out one time), the first instance will be responsible for members with id % 2 == 0, and the second for id % 2 == 1.
To achieve it, i was thinking that on the startup of each instance, i register the current instance in some sql table.

In addition, each web role instance will have background thread that:

1. check the sql table to know which members are on his responsibility
2. handle those members
3. set LastHandleTime date
4. check that if there is a record for an instance that for 5 minutes didn't update its LastHandleTime, remove its record (so someone else will take its members next time)

Edit: There is a problem with this solution also. I cannot keep a background thread running for the all life of my wcf service- the IIS may kill it if there is no activity in my service [for more details: http://forums.asp.net/t/1830688.aspx/1]

Edit2: To solve it, i would run the background thread as a separated windows service. in the future, if needed, i can convert it easly into a worker role.
since the web role and the windows service use the same handling logic except that from the first there is a response, and from the second there is push notification (if needed), i will use a shared dll with the handling logic for both of them.

Which solution is better? how do i solve the problems i presented?

Comment: Actually - here is my blog post about this very topic. Thank you for inspiring me... :)  http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2012/12/27/scalable-distributed-workload-with-azure-queues.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use Windows Services in the cloud, and would avoid using your #2 design as well because it doesn't scale very well. This is the way I would handle your scenario:

I would want to build a Distribution Service (DS) and a Processing Service (SP). The role of the DS is to publish the list of users/members that need to receive notifications in an Azure Queue. The DS can read from the database as you suggest. Using Azure Queues makes it easier to spread workload across worker roles and use a built-in redundancy in which items in a queue reappear if they are not processed in a specific timeframe. The DS could be a background thread in your WCF Service, although I would probably create a dedicated Worker Role for that purpose. If you need to have more than 1 DS for redundancy, use a shared locking mechanism (such as leasing a common Blob or using an Azure Table) so that only 1 DS publishes the list of members to notify in the queue. Each member that needs to receive a notification is represented by a message in an Azure Queue. For example, you could store a user id in the queue: 2019932 - So if you have 10,000 messages to send, you will have 10,000 messages in an Azure Queue.

The SP is another worker role that reads from the queue and processes each item in the queue. The SP can take N items from the queue at a time (let's say 10 for example) and process them. The SP could also have multiple threads (let's say T threads), so each SP could process roughly N * P requests at a time, in parallel. Let's further assume your code take S seconds to process each message (check Facebook, send the notification, update database). To scale, all you need to do is deploy more SPs. Deploying X SPs would give you a throughput of X * N * P / (N * S ) messages per second on average.

You can technically have the DS and the SP in the same worker role; as long as you handle a shared locking mechanism, you don't have to worry about duplicate messages when you deploy your role on multiple machines.

As usual, when you deal with large number of requests, you enter the world of sharding. See this link for the current scalability targets of Azure. For example a single queue can process up to 2,000 messages per second. It's a target... not a guarantee... :)  If you think you will need more than this, you can always use multiple queues.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for you response (i would have vote up but i don't have enough reputation).


Plese tell me why solution #2 is not scalble?
(please notice my "edit2" on it)


About your solution: the DS need to check the queue in while(true) loop, and whenever thq eueue empty, push all my members into the queue? it seem kinda expensive..

Comment: Hi - well, #2 is scalable, my mistake. However, it seems manual if I understand correctly. Walk through the steps involved in adding one more node and see if this acceptable to you. The solution I provide only required deploying a new node; no special configuration needed to add a single node.

Comment: Regarding the DS, it doesn't need to check the queue; it only writes to it. The DS simply checks the database records to see which records need to be processed by checking a date/time stamp. The PS closes the loop by updating the date/time stamp in question. So you would use a SQL statement that satisfies your selection criteria, including the date/time stamp. The DS would simply check the database continuously (such as every minute for example).

Comment: Nothing is manual.. as i wrote: whenever a new node (worker role/windows service) is added, he adds a record in a table to register himself. at the begining on the infinite loop, every node reads from that table, count how many workers there are, and calculate (with mod) the members in his responsability.

Comment: Your method seem to work. in a matter of fact, that was my first plan almost exactly ^_^ (in my original plan, i was thinking about sampling the queue until its empty and then refilling it with all members. another way was that every worker will enqueue the member back to the queue after he finishes handling it) but using that method seem more expensive because i have the costs of using the queue (and if i have hounded of thousands members i guess it counts). now that you understand my idea completely, what do you think about it?

Comment: I think your design will need extra work when dealing with a node failure. What happens when one of the nodes crashes, or fails over? Some of your records will be left untouched, unless you also code for automatic recovery of a failed node. And that becomes much more difficult to build and test. The queuing mechanism avoids that problem entirely. If you do decide to implement your method, please do report back with what worked and what didn't, so we can all benefit from your experience.

Comment: I must misunderstand something. Why do you need to check anything in the queue? If you have enough PS nodes, just read all your records every 30 minutes (or whatever duration) and send them in the queue.

Comment: I agree that failure of the nodes are the "risky part", and that why i mentioned the "LastHandleTime". after each handle, the node updates this column in the table. at the beginning of the loop at every node, just before he count how many workers there are, he also check if there is a node with Timeout (using that column), and if so he removed its record- so someone else takes the responsibility for his members. in addition, when the node shuts down (if azure updates the OS for example), the node removes himself from the table

Comment: Oh and i forgot: there is a situation that a node is still active but for some reason someone else was thinking he is dead. so for handling this rare situation, if a node doesn't find himself in the table (at the beginning stage of the loop), he reinsert himself

Comment: and about your question: 30 minutes is the SLA (also its flexible..). but if the nodes finishes their work earlier, so its better and i want less then 30 minutes.. if i enter all records every 30 minutes that cannot happen. and still, in your design i need 3 components: PS, DS, and a web role to handle requests.. and that in addition to using the queue which had costs of its own. that why i abandoned it basically. I'll be glad to share my code when i'm done :)